# Removing newline characters not working

Tags: python

Im trying to remove the `\n` from a list created in a function. My code for removing it doesnt seem to be working. Im not getting an error either??

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Description:

Basic Domain bruteforcer

Usage:
  your_script.py (-f <file>) (-d <domain>) [-t 10] [-v]
  your_script.py -h | --help

Arguments:
  -f --file File to read potential Sub-domains from. (Required)
  -d --domain Domain to bruteforce. (Required)
Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  -p --proxy    Proxy address and port. [default: http://127.0.0.1:8080] (Optional)
  -t --thread   Thread count. (Optional)
  -v --verbose  Turn debug on. (Optional)
"""
from docopt import docopt


def fread(dwords, *args):
        flist = open(dwords).readlines()
        #print current list
        print flist
        nlist = flist
        for i in nlist:
          i.rstrip('\n')
          return nlist

if __name__ == "__main__":
        arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')
        # print new list with removed \n
        print fread(arguments['--file'])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings are not mutable, `i.rstrip('\n')` *returns* a new string.

Use a list comprehension:

```
def fread(dwords):
    flist = open(dwords).readlines()
    return [s.rstrip('\n') for s in flist]
```

or, since you are reading the whole file into memory anyway, `str.splitlines()`:

```
def fread(dwords):
    return open(dwords).read().splitlines()
```

Comment: in your opinion @Martijn Pieters should I not be reading into memory? which is better practice?

Comment: @LearningCode: You can loop directly over the file object, that'll give you individual lines.

Comment: @LearningCode: `with open(dwords) as fobj:`, `for line in fobj:`, `print fobj.rstrip('\n')`, for example.